# Is it possible to use this legacy https client also for a simple DELETE call?

Tags: rust, hyper

I have this hyper client:

```rust
use http_body_util::{combinators::UnsyncBoxBody, BodyExt, BodyStream, StreamBody};
use hyper_tls::HttpsConnector;
use hyper_util::{
  client::legacy::{self, connect::HttpConnector},
  rt::TokioExecutor,
}
use tokio_util::{
  bytes::Bytes,
  io::{ReaderStream, StreamReader},
};

pub struct HttpsClient {
  legacy_client: legacy::Client<HttpsConnector<HttpConnector>, UnsyncBoxBody<Bytes, std::io::Error>>,
}
```

and I'm using `legacy_client` for code like:

```rust
legacy_client
  .request(
    hyper::Request::builder()
      .method(Method::PUT)
      .uri(uri)
      .header(header::CONTENT_LENGTH, size)
      .body(BodyExt::boxed_unsync(StreamBody::new(ReaderStream::new(stream).map_ok(Frame::data))))
      .unwrap(),
  )
  .await?;
```

Now I would like to use that `legacy_client` also for a simple `DELETE` call. Is it possible?

I tried with:

```rust
let req = hyper::Request::builder()
  .uri(uri)
  .method("DELETE")
  .body(())
  .unwrap();

let resp = legacy_client.request(req).await?;
```

but it throws with:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
    |
128 |     let resp = legacy_client.request(req).await?;
    |                              ------- ^^^ expected `Request<UnsyncBoxBody<Bytes, ...>>`, found `Request<()>`
    |                              |
    |                              arguments to this method are incorrect
    |
    = note: expected struct `hyper::Request<http_body_util::combinators::UnsyncBoxBody<hyper::body::Bytes, std::io::Error>>`
               found struct `hyper::Request<()>`
note: method defined here
    |
201 |     pub fn request(&self, mut req: Request<B>) -> ResponseFuture {
    |            ^^^^^^^
```

How can I fix this?

I would like to use the `hyper_util::client::legacy` because I don't want to add another dependency such as "reqwest" to my project.

Comment: One of hyper authors said I can use one of Rust way to unify types. What does it mean? https://github.com/hyperium/hyper/discussions/3613#discussioncomment-8934676